# Runit logging not working

Tags: ubuntu, logging, runit

I created a service with runit. Service starts and falls without logging. I need information about STDOUT of service for error detection (service starts without runit properly).

I created a directory `/etc/sv/service_name/log`, created **run** executable for logging (setup executable bit too):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec svlogd -t /var/log/service_name
```

And create directory **/var/log/service_name**

However, after service start/restart log directory is empty

I run service as:

```
$ sv start service_name
ok: run: service_name: (pid 17017) 0s
$ sv status service_name
run: service_name: (pid 17373) 1sfail: service_name: runsv not running
```

What's wrong in my logging configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your answer, the clue

```
run: service_name: (pid 17373) 1sfail: service_name: runsv not running
```

tells me that the issue isn't the log, rather, your service itself is failing.  What does `ps fax` report to you?  Do you see a `runsv` with the logger attached to it?  Does `runsv` have the daemon/process attached to it?  Is there an `runsv` at all?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As it turned out, the problem was in permission of service executable